# how general client get Java FX 2 runtime?

Tags: java, javafx-2

If I created a JavaFX 2 web based application, how general user get the Runtime and run my JavaFX 2 application? get once or every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaFX runtime must be downloaded once per machine.

Usually if a user without JavaFX opens a link with a javafx application it will be automatically proposed to him to download JavaFX runtime.